# Looping through rows and alerting values

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to learn jQuery...the syntax is confusing to me. Maybe what I am doing wrong is syntax related.

This line alerts a value of 36:

```
$(alert(('.htCore tbody tr th.ht_nestingParent').length));
```

When I do an inspect in the browser and CTRL+F I only find 6; not 36. So, I'm trying to loop through each one it finds and have it dump to console or alert the html values; this way I can try to figure out why it says 36 instead of 6.

Here is my loop I made...but it's not doing anything when I run it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.htCore tbody tr th.ht_nestingParent').each(function (i) {
        $val = $(this).html;
        alert($val);
    });
});
```

Here is my HTML

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th class="ht_nestingLevels ht_nestingParent"><div class="relative"><span class="rowHeader">1</span>
                <div class="ht_nestingButton ht_nestingCollapse"></div>
            </div></th>
        <td class="">7-ELEVEN</td>
        <td class="">22971161</td>
        <td class=""></td>
        <td class=""></td>
        <td class=""></td>
        <td class=""></td>
        <td class=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="ht_nestingLevels ht__highlight"><div class="relative"><span class="ht_nestingLevel_empty"></span><span class="rowHeader">2</span></div></th>
        <td class="current highlight"></td>
        <td class=""></td>
        <td class="">A</td>
        <td class="">SOUTH MOD 67 ID FACE||7-11 OKLAHOMA COLORS||95-5/8 X 96-3/4||DWG: SO1067RF.OK (102138)||</td>
        <td class="">4</td>
        <td class="">2020-02-20</td>
        <td class="">2020-01-24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="ht_nestingLevels ht_nestingParent"><div class="relative"><span class="rowHeader">3</span>
                <div class="ht_nestingButton ht_nestingCollapse"></div>
            </div></th>
        <td class="">7-ELEVEN</td>
        <td class="">22983321</td>
        <td class=""></td>
        <td class=""></td>
        <td class=""></td>
        <td class=""></td>
        <td class=""></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

My goal is to find those  tags with a class of .ht_nestingParent and then add a blank table row above the .ht_nestingParent and then a blank row under the last of it's children rows; which are the rows below that lack the .ht_nestingParent class.

Comment: `alert($('.htCore tbody tr th.ht_nestingParent').length);`

Comment: Can you show your html and this $(this).html should be $(this).html()

Comment: @Grumpy - Updated; though I tried to shorten the HTML a bit...

Answer (score 1):

This line is not well written

```
$(alert(('.htCore tbody tr th.ht_nestingParent').length));
```

The 36 you receive is the number of character in this string `.htCore tbody tr th.ht_nestingParent`because you're simply alerting the length of the string.

This should give you the correct number

```
alert($('.htCore tbody tr th.ht_nestingParent').length);
```

Comment: Is there a way to use selectors better than what I am doing to accomplish this?

Comment: What about something like this?     `$(document).ready(function() {  
  $('.htCore tbody tr th.ht_nestingParent').each(function($index, $value) {
   console.log($(this).nextUntil('th.ht_nestingParent').html);
  });
 });`

Comment: I don't know how to format the code in the comments. I am trying to do what it says on https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting but it's not working.